# ocaml command line cannot not find "topfind"

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocaml-toplevel

I have top-level installed, and have $OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH setup.

```
export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH=/Users/smcho/.opam/system/lib/toplevel
```

I checked that the directory exists, and has one file `topfind`.

This is my `~/.ocamlinit` file content.

```
#use "topfind"
#camlp4o
#thread
#require "core.top"
#require "core.syntax"
```

The issue is that I have the error message saying it can't find topfind.

```
> ocaml
        OCaml version 4.02.1

Cannot find file topfind.
Unknown directive `camlp4o'.
#
```

With "ustop", I have no error message.

What might be wrong?

This is my ocaml environment setup.

```
> opam config env
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/smcho/.opam/system/lib/stublibs:/usr/local/lib/ocaml/stublibs"; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
OPAMUTF8MSGS="1"; export OPAMUTF8MSGS;
MANPATH=":/Users/smcho/.opam/system/man"; export MANPATH;
MAKELEVEL=""; export MAKELEVEL;
MAKEFLAGS=""; export MAKEFLAGS;
PERL5LIB="/Users/smcho/.opam/system/lib/perl5:"; export PERL5LIB;
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH="/Users/smcho/.opam/system/lib/toplevel"; export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH;
PATH="..."; export PATH;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/34#issuecomment-9321796) by samoth:

> Normally this issue does not exist anymore if you are not using the
>   system compiler. If you are using the system compiler, you can modify
>   you ~/.ocamlinit to load $OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH as done in
>   https://github.com/OCamlPro/opam/blob/master/shell/dot_ocamlinit

So you can either use a different switch or modify your `.ocamlinit`.