# Ocaml: unknown directive `require'

Tags: ocaml, toplevel, ocaml-toplevel

When loading OCaml, I receive this message when loading ocaml at the terminal:

```
   ocaml
    OCaml version 4.07.1

   Unknown directive `require'.
```

What is the problem exactly?

---

I had previously modified my ocamlinit file, because I had some problems. It now contains:

```
(* ## added by OPAM user-setup for ocamltop / base ## 3ec62baf6f9c219ae06d9814069da862 ## you can edit, but keep this line *)


(* Added by OPAM. *)                                                            

let () = try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
 with Not_found -> ()
;;

#require "yojson";;
#use "topfind";;
#camlp4o
#thread;;
Topfind.don't_load ["compiler-libs.toplevel"];;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
(* ## end of OPAM user-setup addition for ocamltop / base ## keep this line *)
```

---

Edit:

I looked at this question before [ocaml command line cannot find “topfind”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508389/ocaml-command-line-cannot-find-topfind), however I did not find it helpful, since nowhere in the answers was it specified that you need to run `eval $(opam config env)` every time before opening ocaml, as someone below has informed me. So I think this person's clarification is useful to have on this site for other people.

Comment: How was it installed? Did you modify anything recently? Any configuration changed?

Comment: @ShadowMitia I modified the file `~/.ocamlinit`, whose contents I have now included below my question. I can't remember how I installed Ocaml.

Comment: `#require` is provided by `topfind`. The error occurs because you try to `#require` before `#use "topfind"`.

Comment: @glennsi I put `#use "topfind"` above `#require`, and it makes the problem worse. I now get: `OCaml version 4.07.1` `Cannot find file topfind.` `Unknown directive` `'require'. `

Comment: How is that worse? Does fewer things work? All I see is that you have more information to help you troubleshoot,  which seems like an improvement. Perhaps you need to install `ocamlfind`, or just run `eval $(opam config env)` if you haven't.

Comment: @glennsl If I write `eval $(opam config env)` on the terminal and then open ocaml, it works. If I do not write `eval $(opam config env)` on the terminal and then open ocaml, I receive `Cannot find file topfind.
Unknown directive `require'.` How come?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30155960/what-is-the-use-of-eval-opam-config-env. You should do this in your shell's init script. If you use bash I think opam adds it to `.bashrc`, but if you use a different shell you have to add it manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ocaml command line cannot not find “topfind”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508389/ocaml-command-line-cannot-not-find-topfind)

Comment: @glenssl What are environment variables?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall put `#use "topfind"` before any `#require` directive. So put `#require "yojson";;` to the end of the `.ocamlinit` file (also it is a good idea to add it after the comment).

The `#require` directive is provided by the `ocamlfind` tool via the `topfind` script, which is loaded into the toplevel via the `#use` directive, which is a standard builtin directive for loading files. The `topfind` file initializes the `ocamlfind` system in the toplevel, so that the toplevel now can access to the `ocamlfind` infrastructure and load libraries installed in the system. If you're using opam to install packages, then do not forget to do `eval $(opam config env)` (or a shorter version, available in opam 2.x `eval $(opam env)`) in your terminal, before starting the toplevel. E.g.,

```
eval $(opam config env)
ocaml
```

and here is the correct contents of the `.ocamlinit` file:

```
(* ## added by OPAM user-setup for ocamltop / base ## 3ec62baf6f9c219ae06d9814069da862 ## you can edit, but keep this line *)


(* Added by OPAM. *)                                                            

let () = try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
 with Not_found -> ()
;;


#use "topfind";;
#camlp4o
#thread;;
Topfind.don't_load ["compiler-libs.toplevel"];;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
(* ## end of OPAM user-setup addition for ocamltop / base ## keep this line *)

#require "yojson";;
```

Comment: did utop add topfind automatically? i just used require without adding topfind.

Comment: Yep, it did add it.